# Strings are immutable! But I can still modify and get a new copy of the original String?

Tags: java, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the advantage of a String be Immutable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407403/whats-the-advantage-of-a-string-be-immutable)

Strings are Immutable?

```
String s = "PROJECT";
```

Here `s` cannot be modified. But `String s2=s.toLowerCase()` will return me a new string. Here still I can get a new copy of the original string! But if Java still wants immutability, then why not restrict the user while modifying the string (throw an exception or something). Then why immutability? Can any one explain why?

Comment: There are many advantages to immutability.  See this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214714/mutable-vs-immutable-objects) and [this one too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407403/whats-the-advantage-of-a-string-be-immutable)

Comment: Woah! Easy on the exclamation marks there! You might hurt yourself.

Comment: "_Here s cannot be modified.But String s2=s.toLowerCase() will return me a new string._"      Thats the point of immutability . If it was mutable , it could return the same string , value changed .

Comment: It is important not to confuse `s` which is a reference to a String, which is not immutable in this example, and the String referenced which is immutable. In other languages, a reference might have a special notation like `&`, however in Java it is the only option for referring to an Object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings are immutable, meaning that this is always true:

```
String s = "PROJECT";
String s2 = s.toLowerCase();

System.out.println(s.equals("PROJECT")); // Prints true
System.out.println(s.equals(s2));        // Prints false
```

In comparison, consider what would happen if Strings were mutable.

```
MutableString ms = "PROJECT";
MutableString ms2 = ms.toLowerCase();

System.out.println(ms.equals("PROJECT")); // Prints false
System.out.println(ms.equals(ms2));       // Prints true
```

This example may seem trivial, but it means that unless you actually re-assign the reference `s` then you can guarantee that `s` will not be changed by any piece of code.

Answer (score 5):

There's a little misconception:

`s` isn't immutable. `s` can easily be assigned a new value (i.e. another refence to *another* `String` object) unless it is `final`.

And just because a `String` instance is immutable doesn't mean that you can't make *another* `String` that derives its value from that first `String` instance but is slightly different.

In fact that's the *only* way how you can "modify" strings in Java: you can't change the content of any given `String` object, but you *can* create a copy that has modified content (that copy is then again immutable!).