# Why java created Strings as IMMUTABLE CLASS?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't strings be mutable in Java and .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93091/why-cant-strings-be-mutable-in-java-and-net)
>   [What's the advantage of a String be Immutable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407403/whats-the-advantage-of-a-string-be-immutable)

can any one please tell me why String class has been created as immutable class,
Any valid reason behind this Design approach?

Please share your thoughts

Comment: A very common question which would have been answered by google.

Answer (score 2):

Because if the String class was *not* final then you could declare a subclass of String which breaks any number of the contracts of the String class, especially *immutability*, and wreak havoc on unsuspecting programmers.

Imagine:

```
class MyString extends String {
  // Override methods which mutate this instance...
}
```

Now whenever a MyString is passed around as a String it could cause all sorts of problems, especially regarding hashing, which depends on the immutability of String.

Answer (score 0):

Because it makes them much easier to use:

- thread safe without synchronization
- usable as a key in Maps
- no need to create defensive copies each time you pass or return them
- poolable
- ...

Comment: These are all great reasons and (correct me if I'm wrong) they all effects of the immutability of string contents, no?

Comment: The question is: "why is the String class immutable?". It's not "why is the String class final?".