# Why string method on a string object doesn't modify the object in Python?

Tags: python

I found it odd that a string method operation on a string object doesn't modify the string object. Why is it? I wasted quite a bit of time yesterday trying to understand why my code wasn't working when I finally discovered this.

Comment: Maybe ask yourself why you thought strings could be modified.  Did the documentation mis-lead you?  Did you make an assumption because some other language works in a different way?  By the way, numbers are also immutable.

Comment: @cdarke Yes I did. I had one of those 'blonde' (no offense to blondes) moments. :D

Comment: Duplicate of [Why doesn't calling a Python string method do anything unless you assign its output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189172/why-doesnt-calling-a-python-string-method-do-anything-unless-you-assign-its-out)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings are immutable types in python. Main advantages of being immutable would be:

- simplify multithreaded programming.
- can be used as dictionary keys (will keep the same hash)

Answer (score 4):

Strings are immutable by design in Python. This is common to many other languages, too, so it's not a Python-specific thing. For the "Why?" please see [these excellent answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407403/whats-the-advantage-of-a-string-be-immutable) here on SO, and also [this great blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/07/19/strings-immutability-and-persistence.aspx) by Eric Lippert.

That's why string operations always return a new string (which you then may re-assign to the same name as before like

```
mystr = mystr.upper()
```

Comment: And you can use `mystr.strip().lower()`

Comment: @warwaruk: True, but you could do that also if the method would modify the string in-place (and also return it). Of course, that would violate another Python principle...

Comment: @warwaruk: That's what I meant by "violating another principle".