# Why String is immutable or final in Java

Tags: java, string, final, immutability

As i was told this is important String Interview question in Java, which starts with discussion of " What is String ", how String is different in java than in C or C++ and then you are asked about immutable objects and you're asked the main question: " Why String is immutable or final in Java ".

Can you share your Ideas ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.uk/2010/10/why-string-is-immutable-in-java.html

Comment: Good and Interesting question

Comment: Related: [What's the advantage of a String being Immutable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407403)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is mainly for **security reasons**. String is used as parameter in network connection, database url etc. It can be easily attacked if it is mutable

Immutability of `String` solves some **synchronization** issues, it makes the `String` thread safe

To support **StringPool** facility

To **cache** the `hashcode` of `String`

To support **class loading mechanism** in which `String` is used as arguments. String being mutable results in wrong class being loaded

Comment: I know you have covered all points. But explanation to each point would be fantastic

Comment: @mohan Raj : you have mentioned the issues , can you please put a little more explanation to each point , may be a little practical example or something

Answer (score 8):

The two main reasons why strings are immutable in many modern languages, including Java, are **security** and **performance** (or, more precisely, chance for optimizations).

The fact that strings are `final` is to ensure their immutability (by forbidding anyone from extending them and making them mutable again).

Comment: I concur. Also related to performance and optimisation, immutable data structures are much easier to reason about especially with multi threaded algorithms. But the core reason in Java originally for java.lang.String being immutable was Security.

Answer (score 8):

The most important reason is **security**.

A lot of security risks would appear if a malicious thread could gain a reference to a mutable String, which is about to be passed into a method that has to validate the String before it performs an important operation. It would be possible for the thread to change the string after it was validated, and then the operation would be carried out using a dangerous String.

Another reason of Why String is immutable in Java is **to allow String to cache its hashcode**

As mentioned above - the most important reason - **security & thread safety**.

Consider a scenario, in a banking application for money transfer - the beneficiary account number is defined in a string as "0789567345". 
If by mistake/intentionally this acc. number is changed, money will go to a wrong account.

Another scenario - if someone change the class name anywhere between processing as ..

```
getClass().getName().subString(0, 5);
```

The Class loader will simply say 'Class Not Found