# Why String is immutable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

> JavaScript strings are immutable. This means that once a string is created, it is not possible to modify it. However, it is still possible to create another string based on an operation on the original string

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures

***I understand what immutable mean***, but i need to know why they built it like this and what the value of this immutable approach?

Note: I reviewed some **Java** [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15967722/why-string-is-immutable-or-final-in-java) but I'm not Java developer, and I can't understand there terms (StringPool, hashcode ...)

Comment: Did you [confuse Java & Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java)? Related: [Are JavaScript strings immutable? Do I need a “string builder” in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185/are-javascript-strings-immutable-do-i-need-a-string-builder-in-javascript)

Comment: They should start emphasizing more on ECMA instead of JavaScript...

Comment: I'm not confuse between java and JavaScript, I'm asking about something in JavaScript, have similarity with something with java. and I need help to answer this question based on JavaScript terms. thank you

Comment: Might be a re-post have you taken a look at this answer ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185/are-javascript-strings-immutable-do-i-need-a-string-builder-in-javascript

Comment: @ShenalSilva thank you, I understand what is immutable. but I need to know what is the benefits.

Comment: "put on hold as primarily opinion-based by@Jens, Terry, Bohuslav Burghardt, torazaburo, Willie Wheeler 2 mins ago" I'm asking about fact, they built it like this then there is reason for that, and should be good reason because most languages use this approach with strings.

Comment: @Terry why this question "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068804/why-is-string-class-declared-final-in-java" did not put on hold as primarily opinion-based. I need to fix my question if I ask it in wrong way.

Comment: Good answeres in [Why are strings immutable in many programming languages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544182/why-are-strings-immutable-in-many-programming-languages)

Comment: this question considered opinion based, but this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365272/why-net-string-is-immutable is not. What's the logic stackoverflow?