# what the reason behind making string immutable in java?

Tags: java, string

why String is immutable or final in java?
Some say because it easy to use immutable string but they try to fail to enplane it.
some say for security reason.
but i can't find the logic behind this.

Comment: You may have to ask to James Gosling!

Comment: I believe @Pawan Mishra want to know **why** we make something like String immutable, not just what immutable means.

Comment: @MrROY that's explained in the other possible duplicate question.

Comment: @MrROY exactly here i want to know **why** string is immutable in java. not the working behind the string manipulation.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Sir i read all the answer of duplicate question but all answer is about the meaning of immutable or implementation of string manipulation.

Comment: There are lot of explanations here on SO. Just another link after visiting those two: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3407403/1065197. Really, you should do some investigation first.