# Regarding constructors Vs Static Factory Methods

Tags: java

I was having a query that is if we have constructor in the class as below..

```
class A
{
  A{}

}
```

Now what is the alternative to the constructors , I have gone for the approach that is static factory methods

```
class A
{
  public staic A getinstance()
  {
return new A();
}

}
```

In the above approch as per the analysis it will return immutable object but I have doubt on this analysis as the object that can be return with static factory method and can later be changed on , How to make it completely immutable..!! please advise..!!

Comment: This can help you [Immutable Objects][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305752/how-to-create-immutable-objects-in-java

Comment: Please take a look of this link [Regarding constructors Vs Static Factory Methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/628950/constructors-vs-factory-methods)

   
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/628950/constructors-vs-factory-methods

Answer (score 1):

*Immutability* is not related to the manner you create your objects. i.e. from *constructors* or *factory methods*.

JDK provides some ways to do this for Collections, using `Collections.unmodifiableCollection` and related methods.

You can also incorporate it into your design, which becomes useful when working with *concurrent* applications.

A complete strategy for this is given here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/imstrat.html

Answer (score 0):

alternative to the constructors : `static factory methods` are not alternative to constructors. But you can have `block intialization` which is equivalent to the constructors, but disadvantage is you can not pass arguments to it like :

```
class B {
  private int i;
  //intialization block, can not pass arguments like constructor
  {
    i=2;
  }
  //getter and setters
}
```

.

```
class A
{
  public staic A getinstance()
  {
    return new A();
  }

}
```

--> well this class will not return immutable object. To make class immutable, make class final, all members private and final, provide only getter methods and parameterised constructor. See below example :

```
final class A
{
   final private int b;
  public A(int b)
  {
    this.b = b;
  }

   public int getB() {
       return this.b;
   }

}
```