# Technique used in java to make string immutable?

Tags: java, string, immutability

Technique used in java to make string immutable?
or how can i make my string class immutable.
I just want to know the logic behind this.

Comment: String is already immutable.

Comment: JDK provides source code for Java standard classes in `src.zip` file. Take a look at String class code and you will see how it is done. Also take a look at [how-to-create-immutable-objects-in-java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305752/how-to-create-immutable-objects-in-java)

Comment: @Pshemo In `src.zip` contain all publicly available source files. but its hard to understand for beginners. :(

Comment: @PawanMishra Nobody said it will be easy :/ That is why I gave you second link so you could see what to looking for. To make viewing easier you can use this file in IDE like Eclipse or NetBeans and press `method()` with Ctrl key to navigate to method declaration/implementation.

Comment: Note: String is effectively immutable, but technically it has two mutable fields in Java 7.  These are used to cache the hashCode(s).

Answer (score 7):

In Java, `String` objects are already immutable.

I can't speak to how the Java language creators specifically made `String` immutable, but here are some [guidelines](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/imstrat.html) that you can follow to make your own classes immutable:

1. Don't use setter methods.
2. Make all fields `private` and `final`.
3. Don't allow methods to be overwritten (either make class `final` or use a factory pattern).
4. If any fields are objects of mutable type, take care when using those objects: Defensively clone them when returning those objects off of a getter method or receiving them in the constructor, and don't provide methods which modify the mutable objects.

Comment: +1 for `either make class final or use a factory pattern` - most of the time have heard of only `final` one but this `factory pattern` seems promising too :)

Answer (score 2):

`String` class in Java is already immutable.

For reference, see the documentation at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

If you want to see how Java String class is implemented, please visit http://docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html