# How to make an ArrayList immutable in Java without API?

Tags: java, immutability

To make the list unmodifiable in a derived class and to the external world, I understand that it must be declared private and final. How would it be modified to make it immutable even within the same class without using the `unmodifiableList` method? I must clarify that this is for a theoretical scenario asked during an interview.

I was told that it has something to do with not allowing changes to `hashCode()`, but can someone please give me a concrete solution? By extension, I also want to know how to make any (custom) object immutable.

Comment: there is a nice discussion here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305752/how-to-create-immutable-objects-in-java

Comment: Just create `MyList` that does not provide methods for modification and `MyList` is-a `List`.

Comment: You could make your own `List` class in which the `add`, `addAll` and `remove` methods throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Comment: Making `List` immutable would make the code bulky. I'm better off creating my own linked list.