# How to maintain mutable with using java streams

Tags: java

I am passing a person list to local method. In this method, I am streaming with passed list and creating a new list. My concern is that if I update for the newly created list, it is affecting the passed list. I am sending piece of code. How to maintain mutable for passed list.

```
private void checkMutable(List<person> personList) {
    List<person> personNewList = personList.stream()
          .map(person->person)
          .collect(Collectors.toList());

    personNewList.stream().forEach(p -> {
        p.setEmail("ccc@gmail.com");
        p.setName("ccc");
    });

    personList.stream().forEach(p -> {
        System.out.println("name : " + p.getName() + "  ---  " + "name : " + p.getEmail());
    });
```

Comment: can some one  give answer for this.

Comment: Your `map(person->person)` serves no purpose. Your new list contains the same objects as the old list. If you alter them, you're altering the original objects. If you want _copies_ of your `person` objects, you need to have some code for copying that object, not just copying the list.

Comment: If you want to deep copy your list, this isnt the best way to do it...

Comment: person->person.clone() might work in this instance, but it doesnt seem nice design on first glance...

Comment: do we have any other way to copy this object without using clone method.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, when you create a new person list`(personNewList)`, you can return a new instance of `Person` instance of returning the same person.

I have added below method in `Person` class

```
public static Person copyOf(Person person) {
    return new Person(person.getEmail(),person.getName());
}
```

and used this method in the `filter` predicate to create a new instance of `Person`

```
List<Person> personNewList = personList.stream().map(person -> 
                             Person.copyOf(person)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you truly want to make the `Person` class mutable, follow below [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305752/how-to-create-immutable-objects-in-java)