# How does immutable object get cached and reused in java?

Tags: java

I have read that immutable object can be cached and reused in java and this is one of the advantage of using immutable object. My question is what's in java responsible for caching immutable object. Where is this logic written in java?

Comment: does this answer to your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305752/how-to-create-immutable-objects-in-java

Comment: It happens because you write code that caches and reuses them. The point is that this can be done *safely*, because there is no risk of two threads corrupting the state of instances they are both using.