# About the String#substring() method

Tags: java, string, performance

If we take a look at the `String#substring` method implementation :

```
new String(offset + beginIndex, endIndex - beginIndex, value);
```

We see that a new String is created with the **same** original content (parameter *char [] value*).

So the workaround is to use  `new String(toto.substring(...))` to drop the reference to the original char[] value and make it eligible for GC (if no more references exist).

I would like to know if there is a special reason that explain this implementation. Why the method doesn't create herself the new shorter String and why she keeps the full original value instead?

The other related question is : should we always use `new String(...)` when dealing with substring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to know if there is a special reason that explain this implementation. Why the method doesn't create herself the new shorter String and why she keeps the full original value instead?

Because in **most** use-cases it is faster for `substring()` to work this way.  At least, that's what Sun / Oracle's empirical measurements would have shown.  By doing this, the implementation avoids allocating a backing array and copying characters to the array.

This is only a non-optimization if you have to then copy the String to avoid a memory leakage problem.  In the vast majority of cases, the substrings become garbage in a relatively short period of time, and there is no long-term leakage of memory.

---

Hypothetically, the Java designers could have provided two versions of `substring`, one which behaved as currently, and the other that created a String with its own backing array.  But that would encourage the developer to waste brain-cycles thinking about which version to use.  And then there's the problem of utility methods that build on substrings ... like the `Pattern` / `Matcher` classes for instance.  So I think it is a good thing that they didn't.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer! So you mean always using `new String()` improve memory management, but it will not make the app faster?

Comment: @alain.janinm - it is more complicated than that.  On the one hand, `new String()` often doesn't improve memory management at all.  On the other hand, when it does improve memory management it will make the app go faster.  Basically, you have to understand your application's behaviour in order to know whether this will improve things.

Comment: Ok I was wondering the same but I was not sure! Thanks for the enlightenment!

Answer (score 2):

Because `String` is [immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279507/what-is-meant-by-immutable) class

**Also See**

- http://javarevisited.blogspot.it/2010/10/why-string-is-immutable-in-java.html (Courtesy: Luca Geretti )

Comment: A useful complementary link on **why** `String` is immutable: [Why String is immutable in Java?](http://javarevisited.blogspot.it/2010/10/why-string-is-immutable-in-java.html)

Comment: @LucaGeretti you should propose that as an edit to the answer.

Comment: @Kazekage: I didn't simply because it is an external link. I'd rather integrate (some of) the content into the answer.

Comment: I know - maybe not enough - that Strings are immutable but I don't understand why it an explanation... I mean they can have call the String constructor with a shorter char[] instead of the original one.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this implementation is efficiency. By pointing to the same `char[]` as the original string, no data needs to be copied.

This does have a downside though, as you've already hinted at yourself. If the original string is long and you just want to get a small part of it, and you don't need the original string anymore after that, then the complete original array is still referenced and can't be garbage collected. You already know how to avoid that - do `new String(original.substring(...))`.

> should we always use `new String(...)` when dealing with substring?

No, not *always*. Only when you know it might cause problem. In many cases, referring to the original `char[]` instead of copying the data is more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it meets up with Stephen C answer!