# BigDecimal is not doing add operation

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have 2 `BigDecimal` numbers. I am trying to add them. My code is as follow:

```
BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal(10);
BigDecimal bd2 = new BigDecimal(10);

bd1.add(bd2);
```

Here I am expecting the value of bd1 20 but again and again it's showing 10. It's not being added. Please help if I have done something wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reimeus is right. You need to assign the value to the result like this:

```
bd1 = bd1.add(bd2);
```

If you want to know details about immutable you can refer to following link:

[What is meant by immutable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279507/what-is-meant-by-immutable)

Answer (score 10):

`BigDecimal` values are immutable, You need to assign the value to the result of `add`:

```
bd1 = bd1.add(bd2);
```

Answer (score 3):

**BigDecimal is immutable.** Every operation returns a new instance containing the result of the operation.

Reading [Java Doc about BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) helps you to understand better.

If you want to store sum of bd1 and bd2 in bd1 , you have to do

```
bd1 = bd1.add(bd2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal(10);
BigDecimal bd2 = new BigDecimal(10);
bd1 = bd1.add(bd2);
System.out.println(bd1); /*Prints 20*/
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the result in a new variable:

```
BigDecimal bd3 = bd1.add(bd2);
```