# Read-only strings in Clisp

Tags: string, readonly, clisp

I'm noticing some inconsistency in the output of this code in `Clisp`:

```
(defvar str "Another")
(setf (char str 3) #\!)
```

When I run it from the repl, I get the desired result:

```
[1]> (defvar str "Another")
STR
[2]> (setf (char str 3) #\!)
#\!
[3]> str
"Ano!her"
[4]>
```

However, when I run it from a script, I get a warning about modifying a readonly string:

```
*** - Attempt to modify a read-only string: "Another"
```

I got that error when running this code:

```
(print (do ((str "foobar")
            (i 0 (+ i 1)))
           ((= i (length str)) str)
         (setf (char str i) #\!)))
```

**What's the point of making the string `read-only`(I'm assuming this is the same as `immutable`) when the binding will dissappear when the block ends?**

**And, why the discrepancy between the two outputs?**

**Lastly, is there a way to turn it off?** I don't find the warning particularly useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution

First of all, what you are seeing is an [`error`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/e_error.htm), not a [`warning`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/e_warnin.htm).

Second, you cannot turn it off, but you can avoid it by [copying](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_cp_seq.htm) the immutable string:

```
(print (do ((str (copy-seq "foobar"))
            (i 0 (+ i 1)))
           ((= i (length str)) str)
         (setf (char str i) #\!)))
```

## Motivation

[Why some data is made immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279507/what-is-meant-by-immutable) is a topic much discussed on the web.

The basic reasons are:

- safety in a multithreaded environment and
- better compilers

## Justification

As per [the manual](http://www.clisp.org/impnotes/gen-ref.html):

> An attempt to modify read-only data SIGNALs an ERROR. Program text and
>   quoted constants loaded from files are considered read-only data. This
>   check is only performed for strings, not for conses, other kinds of
>   arrays, and user-defined data types.

This is explicitly permitted by the [ANSI CL spec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_i.htm#immutable):

> implementations are not required to detect attempts to modify
>   immutable objects or cells; the consequences of attempting to make
>   such modification are undefined

Comment: Soo, that check is not performed in the repl?