# when we write String str="mac"; and again we can initialize with str="joe"

Tags: java, immutability

when we write `String str="mac";`
         and again we can initialize with `str="joe";`
 why this happens when String is immutable where we can initialize only once for immutable object

Comment: Somewhat related - http://stackoverflow.com/q/279507/1679863

Comment: declare string as final static

Comment: you have misunderstood initialize and immutable

Comment: @Peshal Why `static`? Just `final` would be fine. But that isn't the question.

Comment: @Rohit how do you declare the constants?

Comment: @Peshal Why do you need a constant?

Comment: Why do people downvote this question? Everybody was begginer once.

Comment: @LeosLiterak Because looking through tutorials and/or searching Google or Stack Overflow would have found easy answers.

Comment: @chrylis yes, but downvoting is kind of rude, if he tries

Answer (score 2):

String object is immutable, so you cannot modify its content. But you can reassign string variable to different String object.