# Why does 'concat' not change String?

Tags: java, string, concatenation

```
String s1 = "Sk";
s1.concat(" Y");
System.out.println("s1 refers to "+s1);
```

The above code generates the output "Sk" and not "Sk Y". I hope I'm explaining clear enough.Why is this ?

Comment: concat does not change the string, java strings are immutable. try s1 = s1.concat(" Y").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`s1.concat(" Y");` doesn't alter `s1` (it can't, since Strings are immutable).

It returns a new String :

```
String s2 = s1.concat(" Y");
System.out.println("s2 refers to "+s2);
```

Comment: Can You explain immutable in more details or specify a link ?

Comment: @Shashwat There's not much to explain. Immutable object means you can't change its state after you create it. When you write `String s1 = "Sk";`, `s1` refers to an immutable object, so any method you call on `s1` won't change the content of that String. On the other hand, StringBuilder is a mutable object. calling the `append` method of a StringBuilder object changes the content of that object.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279507/what-is-meant-by-immutable