# BigInteger.ValueOf() returns cached objects?

Tags: java, numbers, biginteger

I wrote a test code to check equality. I have checked Java doc and it says `BigInteger` is Immutable. Checking the documentation of the static factory method `valueOf` it looks like it returns the already cached immutable instance. So why does == returns false when its the cached instance.

Below is the Java doc for `valueOf` in `BigInteger`:

> Returns a Big Integer whose value is equal to that of the specified
>   long. This "static factory method" is provided in preference to a
>   (long) constructor because it allows for reuse of frequently used
>   BigIntegers.

The below code is going into infinite loop .

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    while(true) {
        BigInteger a = BigInteger.valueOf(100);
        BigInteger c = BigInteger.valueOf(100);
        if (a == c) {
            break;
        }
 }
```

Comment: `==` tests for reference equality, `.equals()` test for value equality

Comment: Use `equal()` to check for equality.

Comment: For primitive types `==` compares the value, but for objects it compares the references.

Comment: This question is NOT a duplicate of the linked questions.  It is about confusion over the meaning of "immutable", which just means the value cannot be changed. It does not mean that the JVM has to keep only one copy of every value you create.

Comment: This comparision should return true anyway, because the objects received from `valueOf` should be pooled, so the second call should return reference to the same object.

Comment: Here is the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#valueOf%28long%29) for this method, the second call should return the reference to the same object.

Comment: @Tunaki this is not a dup. Please read carefully as it has to do with mutable vs immutable, not `==` vs `equals()`.  I've edited the title for clarity.

Comment: @JimGarrison I feel your edit changes the intent of the question. An immutable object is still an object and the question is inherently about the behaviour of the `==` between objects, when the OP would expect that operator to return `true` here. However, if we then focus on immutability, a duplicate would be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279507/what-is-meant-by-immutable

Comment: @Tunaki this question was intended to learn the static factory method value of whether it is inline with the Java document .

Comment: Please edit your question to make that clearer. Include the parts of the javadoc which are relevant and explain why you think the snippet you provide agrees/disagrees with the javadoc.

Comment: Thanks for editing the question but now, it is clear that all answers have been invalidated. They do not cover that new question at all.

Comment: "it allows for reuse of frequently used BigIntegers" but the criteria by which "frequently used BigIntegers" are defined is not specified in the documentation. Just because the method could return the same instance doesn't mean it will.

Comment: I would expect this code to work for 0/1 as "frequently used" values, I would not expect this check to succeed for anything else.

Comment: ISTM that this question is exactly about this "pooling", and demonstrates it doesn't actually happen. @Tunaki: this is not a duplicate. The meaning of `==` seems to be clear, but the question tests for *identity* (i.e. if the first value is cached and when a second BI with the same value is requested, if it returns the firts one or not), for which `==`is the right choice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Immutable means only that the value cannot change after instantiation.

Specifically, it does NOT mean the JVM has to ensure there's only one copy of each value you create.  You can create many immutable objects having the same internal state but they are still distinct objects.  Comparing these with `==` will return `false` while `equals()` will return `true`.

Answer (score 3):

BigInteger is a reference variable, unlike int, or double, which are primitive variables. This means that you cannot use "==" as you can with ints or doubles. Instead, you must use .equals(), similar to how you would with a String.

Comment: In this case `valueOf` by the second call should return the reference to the same object anyway.

Comment: @Jagger `valueOf` doesn't specify any kind of caching behavior.  It's _allowed_ to cache things, but it is in no way obligated to.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Yep, you are right. For example this `BigInteger.valueOf(100L) == BigInteger.valueOf(100L)` returns `false` and this `BigInteger.valueOf(1L) == BigInteger.valueOf(1L)` returns `true`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman It looks like from `1L` to `16L` the `valueOf` returns the same reference, so in this case `a == c` would return always `true`.

Answer (score 0):

See source of BigInteger:

> // If -MAX_CONSTANT < val < MAX_CONSTANT, return stashed constant

and MAX_CONSTANT is 16

Answer (score -1):

== checks for the reference instead of actual content.  For this reason == is usually used with primitive data type like int,float etc. Immutable means whenever you update a existing value it will not be modified but instead a new one will be created. So in your example even though both are physically same object their references value are different.