# Is a class with only static members immutable?

Tags: java

Is a class with only static members immutable? Or close to being immutable?

Comment: closer than what?

Comment: Do you mean final instead of static?

Comment: @Bathsheba: will the class become immutable

Comment: Aren't static members mutable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Techinically, yes.

[Definition of immutability:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279507/what-is-meant-by-immutable)

> Immutable means that once the constructor for an object has completed execution that instance can't be altered.

Say you have this class:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static int a = 0;
}
```

When you create an instance of this class, you can't "alter" it, because there is nothing to alter, to change the value of! There are no non-static members!

So yeah, such a class is immutable.

Comment: Yes you can, but immutability is only to do with the instance members of the class, nothing to do with static members. MyClass is not an instance of MyClass. @LoganKulinski

Answer (score 1):

If the fields are all `final` and primitive or immutable, then you have an immutable class. Note: just making a field final doesn't make it immutable.

```
// not immutable!
private static final Set<String> words = new HashSet<>();
public static void addWord(String word) { words.add(word); }
```

Note: one exception to this rule on immutable is use of reflection or native methods. Reflection/native methods can attempt to override even final values. One place this is used is in `java.lang.System`

```
public final static PrintStream out = null;
```

So you might conclude that `System.out` is always `null` and you can't write a Hello World program, but oh no this gets set from native code in a manner similar to what this method does

```
public static void setOut(PrintStream out) {
    checkIO();
    setOut0(out);
}
private static native void setOut0(PrintStream out);
```

So in fact, `System.out` does get reset by the JVM on startup and you can reset it using `System.setOut`