# Why Rational is the type that the add method returns? - Java

Tags: java, return-type

Why Rational is the type that the add method returns?

I understand when a method returns a type such as void, int or String but I do not see why Rational.

**Rational class:**

```
public class Rational {

    private int num;
    private int den;

    public Rational(int numerator, int denominator) {

        this.num = numerator;
        this.den = denominator;

    }

    public Rational add(Rational b) {

        int numerator   = (this.num * b.den) + (this.den * b.num);
        int denominator = this.den * b.den;

        return new Rational(numerator, denominator);        
    }
}
```

**Main class:**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // 1/2 + 1/3 = 5/6
        Rational obj1 = new Rational(1, 2);
        Rational obj2 = new Rational(1, 3);
        Rational obj3 = obj1.add(obj2);   
    }
}
```

Comment: When you add two rational numbers, the result is a rational number. Why would you want a different result?

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279507/what-is-meant-by-immutable

Comment: It’s not at all clear what you are asking. Do you understand that a `class` such as this is a type, just like `int` or `String`?

Answer (score 0):

> Why Rational is the type that the add method returns? I understand
>   when a method returns a type such as void, int or String but I do not
>   see why Rational.

`void`, `int` or `String` are JDK predefined types. 
In a method, you can return any type you want : predefined types but also custom types.

In your example, the `add(Rational b)` method has an implementation without side effects. The method does not modify the parameter and returns a **new** instance of `Rational` resulting from the computation.

How do you want to get it if you don't return a `Rational` object in the method?
Returning an array of `int` that contains two `int` would be not desirable. It is not a structured way to represent the information and it is clumsy as you don't encapsulate related data.

Comment: @ pvg if the result of the add() method was performed by modifying the Rational parameter (that is `obj2` client side), in the client side `obj2` would not any longer the value  it had before the method invocation.

Comment: @pvg You forget  the sentence that introduces it  : "In your example, the add(Rational b) method has an implementation without side effect on the input parameter."  "As instructions in the method cannot modify directly the parameter" is a direct consequence. I state that the method is without side effect, so it cannot change the parameter state.It is rather logical but I was perhaps not very clear.

Comment: Not it is your interpretation that differs from mine. Discussing a so little detail has no value. Sincerely.

Comment: if you decide to have a method without side effect on the input parameter, you cannot modify the state of the parameter. Is it not logical for you ?

Comment: "'no side effects' is not a constraint introduced in the question or in the implementation".  I don't agree with. The implementation is clear. It creates a new Rational and returns it instead of using the parameter to return the result while the method could do it. This conveys that the method is without side effect on the parameter. If you want to learn what a side effect is : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)

Answer (score 0):

In your case, `Rational` is implemented as an [**immutable object**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html), meaning that the values of an instance can not be changed after it has been created.

So in order to get the result of an operation like `add()`, since it can't update the values of the current instance, it needs to create and return a new instance that got the updated values passed to its constructor.

EDIT: Assuming your object is meant to be used in an immutable way, you should add the `final` modifier to its private fields to ensure that they aren't accidentally assigned anywhere but in the constructor.

Comment: Rational is not, as shown, immutable to other instances of Rational.

Comment: Why? None of the instance variables are being assigned anywhere but in the constructor.

Comment: The state can be changed right in the method you're talking about. Add can absolutely update the fields.

Comment: It could, but it doesn't. It actually won't even compile the way it's currently written. I updated my answer about that.

Comment: You wrote it can't. But it can. Your update makes it even wronger. It would compile, requires no accessors. Also you can't chide the implementor the class is not implemented to be immutable because nobody claimed it ought to be, nor does it have anything to do with the question.

Comment: True, I assumed the part about it being immutable because I had exactly this class, with the same fields and methods, in a university exercise a few years ago. And that was basically the whole point that it boiled down to.

I have to admit that I wasn't aware that the private modifier doesn't restrict access if it's a field in an instance of the same class.