# Immutable function arguments in java

Tags: java, final

I am new to java and I've come across this question:
in C/C++ we have **const** modifier which makes function parameters **Immutable**, Therefore user is confident that the arguments they pass wont change.

But I could not find the same thing in java. Sure **final** modifier makes the field assignable only once and it works fine to some extent. But what about Objects that I need to modify before sending?(I could make a final copy of the Object but I don't find it good enough. correct me if I'm wrong). what about Object's fields? how we can pass an Object in a way that we would be confident of the integrity of the Object?

Comment: You might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279507/what-is-meant-by-immutable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java immutability is an intrinsic property of the type.

For instance `String` is immutable. No need for **const**. `StringBuilder`, `CharSequence` are, or maybe, mutable. So will need a copy. In these cases a quick `.toString()`. will do the job.

C++ defaults to an implicit copy for arguments. Copying is in someways a better version of immutability. `const &` is kind of effectively a way of getting a copy without paying for it. (I'm sure many people will strongly disagree with this paragraph.)

Comment: Thanks! although its still a bit strange for me to make a final-copy of the object. something I found interesting was that there some classes that have sub-classes which overrides the set functions and then passes it thus making it impossible to modify. How do you find this solution? and just a minor question, making a final copy of an object makes the fields of the field immutable as well?

Comment: @DanaAfa In many cases it makes sense to make the only version of a type immutable. Perhaps with a builder, although they are a faff.