# How to replace characters in a very large string using java causing large memory?

Tags: java, string, memory

I have a large `String` in which I need to replace a few string pathern.

I have written code as below and I am getting very large memory usage in deployed environment.

I have read online to see if there is any more optimal way this can be re-written but could not find conclusive answer.

Can anyone give any suggestions for code below.

```
    String response = "@very #large  & string % STUFF";
    System.out.println(response);
    String[] SPECIAL_CHARACTERS = {"&","%","#","STUFF"};
    for(int count = 0;count<SPECIAL_CHARACTERS.length;count++)
    {
        if(response.contains(SPECIAL_CHARACTERS[count]))
        {
            response = response.replace(SPECIAL_CHARACTERS[count],"");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(response);
```

Comment: Ahh, the bothersome immutability of Java/.NET world. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279507/what-is-meant-by-immutable

Comment: What is the source of the string (for example Web Request), and what is the destination of the output(for example File / database)?

Comment: I am getting data from database having these special characters and then in java code replacing it and returning it in REST API response. I can't do replacement in DB sql due to performance consideration.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a large `String` in which I need to replace a few characters.

I would avoid getting into that situation.  Stream your data!  (And how come you have a "very large" string stored in the database?  That doesn't sound good.)

If you can't, this is the most memory efficient way to do what you are doing:

```
   int len = response.length();
   for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
       char ch = response.charAt(i);
       switch (ch) {
           case '&': case '%': case '#': case '@':
               break;
           default:
               System.out.print(ch);
       }
   }
   System.out.println();
```

In some circumstances, it may be better to use a `StringBuilder` so that you can do a single write operation.

```
   int len = response.length();
   StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder(len);
   for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
       char ch = response.charAt(i);
       switch (ch) {
           case '&': case '%': case '#': case '@':
               break;
           default:
               temp.append(ch);
       }
   }
   System.out.println(temp.toString());
```

but that allocates more memory.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I missed mentioning that the text to be replaced can be a string (thus I created a String array). I am trying to think how would this code snippet would work in that  case as I have to write a generic code to replace a specific text. I have updated my question to reflect same. In this case, I guess I would need to use String.replace() function which causes memory issue. Do you think same?

Comment: You can easily modify the snippets to handle that.  You might end up replacing the switch with a sequence of `if else` statements or a loop.  But I have answered the question **that you asked**.  Avoid using `String.replace()` because each time you call it you copy the entire string.

Comment: The key to modifying the snippets will be to understand how they work.  Read the code.  It is pretty obvious when you think about it.

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this kind of problem by reading packets from the input and append them to the output. So, assuming that the very large `String` is called `input`, I would always read easily manageable packets from `input` into `temp`, do the algorithm of replacements for `temp` and then append `temp` to `output`, which should be initialized before your cycles as empty `String`.

The problem you encounter is that you are always replacing your whole `String`. So, instead of replacing response each time, do all the replacements on smaller packets and add the result to a `String` variable.

Comment: I am not not sure I am following it. A code sample would be handy.

Comment: @satish in order to do that I would need to test it before posting it here, but I'm lazy to do so. If you want, you can try implementing it and you may ask questions when you are stuck.